# How do you implement AKS test in Java to determine whether a number is prime?

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization

I wrote some pseudo code to start with. I am having trouble writing an expandPolynomial() method. Also, I don't know how to represent the arbitrary int x in isPrime().
Here is a link that explains AKS: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HvMSRWTE2mI

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println(isPrime(n));
    }
    private static boolean isPrime(int p)
    {
        /*
        AKS primality test says that if
        ((x-1)^p - (x^p-1)) mod p == 0,
        then p is a prime
        */
        int x;
        boolean prime=true;
        int[] arr = expandPolynomial(x-1, p);
        for (int i=1;i<arr.length-1; i++)
        {
            // arr[0] and arr[arr.length-1] omitted
            // due to the subtraction in the test
            if (arr[i] % p != 0)
            {
                prime = false; 
            }
        }
        return prime;
    }
    private static int[] expandPolynomial()
    {
        /* 
        return the coefficient of each term
        from the leading term to x^1;
        */
    }
}
```

Comment: I give a version in Scheme at [my blog](https://programmingpraxis.com/2012/10/05/aks-primality-prover-part-2/); there is also a Python version there. As DanaJ says, AKS is interesting to know, but not a practical method of proving primality.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately that video is very misleading in a number of ways.

What Dr. Grime spends most of the video describing is equation (1) from [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test).  It's Lemma 2.1, also equation (1) in [the paper](https://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/manindra/algebra/primality_v6.pdf).  It was known in the 1600s and is exponential time.  It's in fact slower than simple trial division.  There is really little point in implementing this other than just for pure fun.

Dr. Grime knows this isn't really AKS, and mentions "some other fiddly bits" near the end, which is in fact *the whole point* of AKS.  Thousands of people for hundreds of years had looked at that equation, maybe gone about different ways of proving it, maybe related it to things like Pascal's triangle (or Tartaglia's triangle, Yang Hui's triangle, the Khayyam triangle, Pingala's, etc if you'd prefer).  One of the most amazing things about AKS is that these three people looked at the same equation as thousands before them, and managed to show how reduce the equation in size and number of tests to bounds that grow slowly enough that the time taken is polynomial (which is certainly not true of the original).

It is possible to implement the real AKS test in Java -- it's been done at least once.  It takes more work since you need to do some modular polynomial multiplication (modular in both the coefficients and the exponents).  More importantly you have to be **extremely** careful with the various limits and comparisons.  Otherwise you get, like many have done, a test that doesn't work correctly.  For instance, if you fail to notice, buried in the second paragraph of page 3, "We use log for base 2 logarithm" then there's a good chance you'll do it wrong and never know you've written a really slow "probable prime" test.  Unlike ECPP, the result of AKS is either "...compute for hours/days/years...  COMPOSITE" or "...compute for hours/days/years... PRIME".  No explanation for why.  No way to double check the results other than run a different test.  ECPP gives you a certificate explaining exactly why the number is prime (albeit ECPP is rather more complicated).

Let's say you do manage to get this written correctly.  It's still not useful, as the fastest implementations in C are still slower than other known and in-daily-use primality proof methods.  I'm not talking about probable prime algorithms (which are orders of magnitude faster yet), I mean APR-CL and ECPP.  Proofs.  To use the video's terms, they are "fool-proof tests for primes" which were known and in use before AKS and continue to be used now.  The video once again misleads the viewers into thinking this was new and unique.

If you're writing a paper that needs some limit on the computational complexity of primality testing, then AKS is great.  "By [AKS2002] primality is in P.  Moving on to my interesting point, ..."  If you're writing something because it interests you, then have at it.  I've done it as have others.  It's fun.  But it's not all that useful in a practical sense.

Add:  If you look at [RosettaCode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/AKS_test_for_primes), you can find example code in over 50 different languages for this lemma.  Java is one of them.

Comment: Nice answer, just a note: The code in http://rosettacode.org/wiki/AKS_test_for_primes#Java is not exactly what I'd recommend to anyone. Especially, `if (n < 0 || n > 63) System.exit(0); // gracefully deal with range issue` is a perfect recipe for a disaster. ;)

Comment: @maaartinus Hmmm... if `System.exit(0)` is a graceful way to deal with bad input, I wonder what they consider graceless?  I guess it's preferable to the Blue Screen of Death.

Comment: @maaartinus, good point.  Hopefully someone will replace it with a well-written version soon.

Answer (score 1):

`x` is not a Java variable that has an actual value.  It's a symbol in a polynomial.  Here you want to represent an actual polynomial in Java, not a single value; so, for instance, for *x*<sup>2</sup> + 3 *x* + 5, you might want to represent this as an array [1, 3, 5], the coefficients of the polynomial (although it's probably better to do it in reverse, [5, 3, 1], with the coefficient of *x*<sup>0</sup> first--I think this makes the algorithms smoother).  So to represent *x*-1, you'll need an `int[]` whose values are [1, -1] or [-1, 1].  You could write a multiplication method that multiplies two polynomials; to multiply *a*<sub>0</sub> + *a*<sub>1</sub> *x*<sup>1</sup> + *a*<sub>2</sub> *x*<sup>2</sup> ... by *b*<sub>0</sub> + *b*<sub>1</sub> *x*<sup>1</sup> + *b*<sub>2</sub> *x*<sup>2</sup>, the coefficient of *x*<sup>0</sup> in the result is *a*<sub>0</sub> b<sub>0</sub>; the coefficient of *x*<sup>1</sup> will be *a*<sub>0</sub> *b*<sub>1</sub> + *a*<sub>1</sub> *b*<sub>0</sub>, of *x*<sup>2</sup> will be *a*<sub>0</sub> *b*<sub>2</sub> + *a*<sub>1</sub> *b*<sub>1</sub> + *a*<sub>2</sub> *b*<sub>0</sub>, and so on.  Using this approach, you could represent *x*-1 as a polynomial and then multiply it by itself *p* times (using your polynomial multiplication method) to get the polynomial (*x*-1)<sup>p</sup>; then you subtract the *x*<sup>p</sup> and *x*<sup>0</sup> coefficients (to implement the `-(x^p-1)` part), and see if all the resulting coefficients are divisible by `p`.

Or, instead of doing all the polynomial math, you could use the fact that the coefficients of (*x*-1)<sup>p</sup> will be the binomial coefficients (also found in Pascal's triangle), with every other sign switched.  But the sign doesn't matter when testing for divisibility by *p* anyway.  So you could simply perform the test by computing all the binomial coefficients and seeing if they're divisible by *p*.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test#Concepts which says the same thing.  To get all the binomial coefficients, start with 1, then multiply by `p` and divide by 1, then multiply by `p-1` and divide by 2, then multiply by `p-2` and divide by 3, etc.

Of course, doing this is actually slower than just running through odd numbers and seeing if `p` is divisible by any of them--the old boring way to check for primality.  The Wikipedia article on the AKS test gives an algorithm that actually does appear to be faster, but it involves things like multiplicative orders and Euler's totient function, so it's too complex to explain here.